# I want to add an If condition in a while loop to check for same string in every line in 2 files and print other columns in the files if they match

Tags: bash

## Contents in data.csv

```
John.duff@example.com status
Hill.ref@example.com status
David.nelson@example.com status
```

## Contents in data2.csv

```
John.duff@example.com unique_user_id
Hill.ref@example.com unique_user_id
David.nelson@example.com unique_user_id
```

*My sample code:*

```
While read c1.f1 c2.f1 c1.f2 c2.f2;
Do 
Echo “$c2.f2 $c2.f1”
Done<paste data.csv data2.csv
```

This code will print me the values in 2nd columns of the both the files but I need some kind of validation before this like adding “if statement” to check whether email id’s of the users in first columns are equal in both files before printing 2nd columns. I want to print unique_user_id’s and status only by mapping the email id’s Can I do that?? Or can I do this better with the awk command and what is the best way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: FYI, CSV == comma separated values.  There are no commas in your files :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick script I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# using your method
paste data.csv data2.csv | while read file1_email file1_value file2_email file2_value
do
    if [ "$file1_email" == "$file2_email" ]
    then
        echo "$file1_email, $file1_value, $file2_value"
    fi
done

echo "------------------------------------------"

# this is mine
while read file1_email file1_value
do
    file2_counter=$(grep -c $file1_email data2.csv)
    if [ $file2_counter -gt 0 ]
    then
        file2_line=$(grep $file1_email data2.csv)
        file2_value=$(echo $file2_line | awk '{print $2}')

        echo "$file1_email, $file1_value, $file2_value"
    fi
done <data.csv
```

- The problem with your approach, it that it takes for granted that the address emails will always appear in the same lines in both files.
- ex. if data2.csv has a different sorting applied, it could have all the same email addresses than in data2.csv.  But the `paste` command will not sort anything, just display the data as it reads it.
- That is why I came up with a different approach.  Read the email address from data.csv, search in data2.csv if it is there, if yes, extract the value form it, and print all that data.

If you use my method, it will loop through every line of data.csv.  But data.csv must be "clean" since the `read` assumes 2 fields.  The first one being the email, the second one being the value.  You should have a look at the data.csv content.

Then once in the while, it checks if the email read from data.csv is present in data2.csv.  If it is not, nothing is done (there is no `else` to the `if`).  But if you want to do something anyway, add an `else` and some code.

Comment: Hello Nic Thank you so much for quick response! Your method is working for me but somehow it's missing few rows of data or email id's. This is because If there is no matching pattern found in some row then the execution being stopped.  what would be the best way to remediate this Issue? Once again thank you so much for your help on this! :) @Nic3500

Comment: I added some comments in the answer.